# Expressions in attributes

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Expressions in attributes always seem to be evaluated before the class itself has been initialized.

i.e:

```
<custom-ele key="{{$.sourceKey}}"></custom-ele>
```

In this case, if I bind an attribute in custom-ele with @NgAttr('key'), it will always come back null, even if the get sourceKey method returns a hard coded value. It's as if the function has not been initialized before the expression is evaluated.

Any help would be appreciated

P.S. is there anywhere I can find comprehensive documentation on how to use expressions in the DOM (and attributes)? The API docs on the official site gives pretty poor coverage.

Comment: Do you really want to start with Angular.dart 1.x? Why not start with Angular 2 Dart? Anyway, what is `$` supposed to do, can't remember seeing this in Angular.dart.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for replying as usual :p
If it was up to me I would upgrade to 2, I am using AngularDart 1.x at work, and with AngularDart 2 still being in beta, it might be difficult to persuade management to upgrade. Especially with how long the migration may take. I can imagine with AngularDart 2 being unified with JS & TS, it will be a lot easier to find help on matters like this though.

Comment: I guess the answer to your question is: only here on SO or in the Angular.dart source code.

Comment: Don't really understand your question, `$.sourceKey` is an expression, function or an object? If it's an object, try to use `@NgOneWay('key')` instead of `@NgAttr('key')`. You can also ditch the curly braces when using `@NgOneWay('key')` to pass whatever objects, strings or whatever to the child component.

Comment: @pandawarrior Thanks for the reply. $.sourceKey is a getter for a static string in the parent element of custom-ele. I am already using <code>@NgOneWay</code> in the custom-ele component in the same way you mentioned.